# Alert dialog from Android service

Tags: android, service

How do I display dialog from a service?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29804684/2149195

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[android-smspopup](http://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/) does exactly that.

A service receives a sms and it starts an `Activity` with:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

**EDIT:** The dialog activity is started [here](https://github.com/everythingandroid/android-smspopup/blob/master/SMSPopup/src/main/java/net/everythingandroid/smspopup/service/SmsReceiverService.java#L201) with this code

```
private void notifyMessageReceived(SmsMmsMessage message) {
    (...)
    context.startActivity(message.getPopupIntent());
    (...)
}
```

With `getPopupIntent()` declared as followed (code [here](https://github.com/everythingandroid/android-smspopup/blob/0c35d12710bd8bc3b0f91e6e4c5e183329b5d4c1/SMSPopup/src/main/java/net/everythingandroid/smspopup/provider/SmsMmsMessage.java#L293)):

```
public Intent getPopupIntent() {
    Intent popup = new Intent(context, SmsPopupActivity.class);
    popup.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    popup.putExtras(toBundle());
    return popup;
    }
```

[`SmsPopupActivity`](https://github.com/everythingandroid/android-smspopup/blob/0c35d12710bd8bc3b0f91e6e4c5e183329b5d4c1/SMSPopup/src/main/java/net/everythingandroid/smspopup/ui/SmsPopupActivity.java) class obviously defines the dialog activity. Its declared as followed in [`AndroidManifest.xml`](https://github.com/everythingandroid/android-smspopup/blob/0987807ba71e0e7488a049c2b702e0dd75029782/SMSPopup/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L64):

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.SmsPopupActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="user"
        android:taskAffinity="net.everythingandroid.smspopup.popup"
        android:theme="@style/DialogTheme" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: thank you, it's few hours searching and trying new ways. thanks it works.

Answer (score 29):

Another way without using an activity:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                    .create();

alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
alertDialog.show();
```

Please note that you have to use this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Comment: Just needed a quick way to choose something after starting my service for debugging purpose, exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT has been deprecated, use TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT

Answer (score 22):

## Material styled Dialog from a Service

From a Service, you can easily show a Material Design styled Dialog manipulating its Window type, attributes and LayoutParams.

### Before we begin: AppCompat Library

This guide presumes you are using Android AppCompat libray.

### Before we begin: Permissions

This method needs the **SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW** permission.
Usually a Service that wants to display a Dialog also has some Views drawn over the system UI (added using `WindowManager.addView()` method) so you might have already declared this permission usage inside you manifest. If not, add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

In **Android 6.0 Marshmallow**, the user must explicitly allow your app to "draw over other apps".
You can programmatically start the system settings Activity that contains the switch:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        openOverlaySettings();
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void openOverlaySettings() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                                     Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_OVERLAY);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RC_OVERLAY:
            final boolean overlayEnabled = Settings.canDrawOverlays(this);
            // Do something...
            break;
    }
}
```

### Create your custom Material Design Dialog theme

Inside `themes.xml` create this theme and customize it with your app colors:

```
<style name="AppTheme.MaterialDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/brand_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/brand_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/brand_accent</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_background_light</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/secondary_text_light</item>
</style>
```

### Launch your Dialog

Inside your Service:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppTheme_MaterialDialogTheme);

dialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
dialogBuilder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message);
dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.btn_back,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
);

final AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
final Window dialogWindow = dialog.getWindow();
final WindowManager.LayoutParams dialogWindowAttributes = dialogWindow.getAttributes();

// Set fixed width (280dp) and WRAP_CONTENT height
final WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(dialogWindowAttributes);
lp.width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 280, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
dialogWindow.setAttributes(lp);

// Set to TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT so that the Service can display it
dialogWindow.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
dialogWindowAttributes.windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
dialog.show();
```

Comment: What is `RC_OVERLAY`?

Comment: @avi It's a request code Integer. You May choose any number and set it in a constant!

Comment: @araks thanks, it's great. you just need to set "lp" after "dialog.show()"

Answer (score 5):

The documentation suggests that you should make use of notifications. Re-evaluate why you might need to use dialogs. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: perhaps an alarm clock? there are reasons to have a popup sometimes!

Answer (score 2):

firstable you need to cast your Activity in Service 
so in your Activity add

```
public static Activity mactivity;
```

and in On create add this

```
mactivity = YourActivity.this;
```

and when we move to your Service alse declare this :

```
YourActivity mact;
YourActivity act;
```

and in on Create service this is our casting

```
mact = (YourActivity) act.mactivity;
```

and  the alert dialog will be  look like this :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mact);
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.string));
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.chat);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.Ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               your message
            }
        });
```

remember that `mact` is the Cast class to use in Alert Builder ...that works fine for me hope it help .

Answer (score 2):

I am calling the below, inside the service when I need to show a dialog.

```
public void ShowYesNoDialog() {

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which) {
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    //Yes Button Clicked
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    //No button clicked
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Did the dialog display?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
    .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT); 
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Make sure you have the below permission added to the manifest.
    android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

I also think that for SDK 23 and above, the user should explicitly set the "Draw over other Apps" permission from the Application manager for the App that starts this service.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://goo.gl/TC9uX) is a more detailed explanation how to display `AlertDialog` from the service using translucent `Activity`, and how to avoid some issues.