# Service displays an Allow/Deny AlertDialog through an Activity. How to get user's choice back in service?

Tags: android

I have  a background service running that needs to display an Allow/Deny AlertDialog to the user and get his choice.
Roughly, this what I want. In my service, I have a code like this:

```
void someMethod()
{
    boolean allow = showAllowDenyBox();
    //Some operations based on the value of allow
}
```

I want to know how to implement the method showAllowDenyBox(). From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814126/display-alertdialog-as-system-overlay-window-from-service) thread, I understand that I have to create an Activity and show the AlertDialog in that Activity. However, once the user selects Allow or Deny, how will I report that choice back to the service? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

In short, I want an AlertDialog to be spawned from inside a service and that must be synchronous.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use the [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) method to implement this functionality. FOr more information on returning a result check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497205/how-to-return-a-result-startactivityforresult-from-a-tabhost-activity).

Basically using this method you inform the Android system that you want to get a result back from the activity you have passed to this method. Setting that result is explained very well in the above post. Do check it out.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is that in my service, I have to execute the next line of code only after I get the result from the Activity. If I use startActivityForResult, it tries to finish executing the calling code and only then starts the Activity. I cannot use this as I want the result from the Activity to execute the next line of code in the calling code.

Comment: You could add the next line(s) of code to a function that's executed in the `onActivityResult` method.