# How to pass argument to Context in android

Tags: android

I am new to android ,
some times my application works fine if i pass

If I use,

```
this for context // sometimes gets error
```

If I use,

```
ClassName.this for context // sometimes gets error       

android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:
   Unable to add window -- token   
android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@40537450 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

If I use,

```
getApplicationContext()

android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: 
Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

If I use,

```
ClassName.this.getParent()
```

I am confused when to use what.

Please Explain

Comment: :D I think you are displaying a dialog.. which is not possible without activity context (in your words ClassName.this). So make sure your activity is running. Thats it.

Comment: What is your question/problem ? The errors you get are certainly not only related on which form of Context you're using.

Comment: I am not really sure, but I think you can have more context in your app, so you max be using a bad one when you are getting these errors. You might want to study this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android

Comment: @Sw4Tish in intent,Intent in = new Intent(packageContext, cls), for packageContext i can pass this,this.getParent(),getApplicationContext(). And in, TextView text = new TextView(context); i can pass this,getContext()

Comment: @PankajKumar yes i am displaying dialog,can you please explain more?

Comment: So you can not display dialog without Activity context. Read more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918571/how-to-display-a-dialog-from-a-service if you are trying to show dialog from Service/ Receiver