# Unable to dismiss AlertDialog

Tags: android

Hi need to show a AlertDialog from a Service.

This is my implementation.

I added the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

But I am not able to dismiss the dialog!!!

I click the OK button but id does not go away!!!

And all the system freezes on that dialog !!!

Please help!!!

```
public class CreditcheckService extends IntentService {
AlertDialog dialog;
public CreditcheckService() {
    super("CreditcheckService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            getApplicationContext());

    builder.setMessage(R.string.please_connect).setTitle(
            R.string.unable_to);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.okay_action,
            new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg,
                int which) {dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    dialog= builder.create(); 
    dialog.getWindow().setType(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Call dialog.dismiss(); in onClickListenr ()

Comment: @Manveer Chawla thanks Manveer, tried it, without success :-(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",null);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();   
}
```

Comment: so if you replace all code with in your onHandleIntent methode you have no sucess? So i think not the code inside the method is your problem... what happens if you let the method empthy?

Answer (score 4):

This is working for my service

```
              try{
                    new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Looper.prepare();
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    getApplicationContext());

                            builder.setMessage("My messgae").setTitle("My Title");
                            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg,
                                                            int which) {dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });

                            dialog= builder.create();
                            dialog.getWindow().setType(
                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                            dialog.show();
                            Looper.loop();
                        }
                    }.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```