# How to show alert dialogs at any time on a high-frequency live card?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm working on Glassware that needs to be able to display alert dialogs at any time during the lifespan of the Glassware. As can be seen on [Google's GDK development guide](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/card-design?hl=de#alert), this requires a valid `Context` object. However, I'm using the high-frequency live card design paradigm, and thus it uses a `Service` (rather than an `Activity`) as its main class. If I try to pass the service as the context to the alert dialog constructor, I get a `BadTokenException`.

Is there a recommended way to show alert dialogs at any time with this type of Glassware? I have been able to show them successfully from the Glassware menu, since the menu is indeed an activity with a usable context object, but I need to be able to show alerts when the menu is closed, too.

For the record, I have been able to find a couple of possible solutions that seem pretty hacky: create a separate dialog-themed activity, or use a system alert, as seen in the top two posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918571/how-to-display-a-dialog-from-a-service). I'd rather avoid these if there's a better way to do it.

**Edit:**
I've accepted the one answer given so far, but if anyone does know of a more "official" way to do it, please post a second answer and I'll probably accept it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a CustomAlertDialogBuilder that extends AlertDialog.Builder and use the service as the context.

Once you have your alert dialog however I don't believe you can avoid:

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```