# Android- > Service -java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception, progressdialog

I used a service for syncing process in my android app. Now i want to add a progress bar to show that syncing process is going on. But when start the service app stops showing following error. But i don't know why it's happen,

Error,

```
10-23 05:27:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(25458): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
10-23 05:27:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(25458): Process: com.abc, PID: 25458
10-23 05:27:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(25458): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 05:27:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(25458):    at com.abc.service.SynchingService$1.run(SynchingService.java:51)
10-23 05:27:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(25458):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

this is my code for service,

```
public class SynchingService extends Service {

private Timer t;
private static MainActivity mainActivity;
ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    this.timer();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

private void timer() {
    t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mainActivity, getString(R.string.dialog_saving), getString(R.string.dialog_please_wait));
                }
            });
            callSync();

        }
    }, 1000, 1000 * 60 * 60);

}

/**
 * This method is used to call every table to start syncing
 * 
 * @param Nothing
 * @return No return value
 */
private void callSync() {

    DataManager datamanager = DataManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    Log.d("service", "running");
    // sync contact data
    ContactSync contactSync = new ContactSync();
    contactSync.contactGroupSync();
    contactSync.contactSync();

    Log.d("service2", "running2");
    // sync horse data
    HorseSync horseSync = new HorseSync();
    horseSync.horseSyncWithServer();

    Log.d("service3", "running3");
    // sync blog data
    BlogSync blogSync = new BlogSync();
    blogSync.blogSyncWithServer();

    Log.d("service4", "running4");

    // delete news categories from local DB.
    datamanager.deleteNewsCategories(MainActivity.mainActivity);
    // delete news from local DB.
    datamanager.deleteNews(MainActivity.mainActivity);
    // delete advertisement categories from local db.
    datamanager.deleteAddCategories(MainActivity.mainActivity);
    // delete advertisements from local db.
    datamanager.deleteAdds(MainActivity.mainActivity);

    dialog.dismiss();

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: your `mainActivity` is `null`

Comment: first: DO NOT STORE UI(Activity) REFERENCES INSIDE SERVICE, second: you should use Messenger class to communication between service and activity ...

Answer (score 0):

because in your case `mainActivity` is `null`. you didn't initialized it.

Comment: mainActivity.runOnUiThread will also cause a crash, and you cannot replace the activity reference by getApplicationContext() since runOnUiThread is not a method of Context...

Comment: it would be ok if they will create a `public satatic Acitivty mainActivity` in `MainActivity` and initialize there. and here they can access.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize your `mainActivity` variable, so this line will cause a crash :

```
mainActivity.runOnUiThread
```

It's generally not a good idea to show a Dialog from a Service, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918571/how-to-display-a-dialog-from-a-service) and its accepted answer for details.
You can look at this from a UX point of view : if you use the `Service` to sync data whether your app is open or not, that means you want to show a `Dialog` (thus blocking UI) that your app is syncing when the user might be performing a totally different task on his device, not related to your app, and I think we can agree that's bad. Or you use the `Service` to sync data only when your app is open, in which case you could just use an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: how can i initialize it??

Comment: I edited my answer, please see the link about showing Dialogs in a Service. The bottom line is don't use a Dialog, use a Notification instead.

Comment: so how can i add service to sync data when my app is open /?

Comment: Use AsyncTask instead, and don't forget to check if the activity is still open once the talk finished executing before doing to update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add new class to your project for getting context

So you can do it like :

Add new class and extend it from Application

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

and Declare it at manifest:

```
<application android:name="com.xyz.MyApplication">
</application>
```

Finally you can use that class when will you need context :)

Comment: This will not fix the issue of the crash caused by mainActivity.runOnUiThread, you cannot call runOnUiThread on Context.

Comment: Ok, Yes @2Dee you right,Another Solution is using Messenger for communication with ui thread,Because service is viewless

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging) will provide good example