# How to show a pop up dialog from your app when screen is locked on Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-popupwindow

How can I push a pop-up from my app to the user when the screen is locked on android?

Comment: use a notifiation? that's what they're there for, especially in lollipop, which adds notifications to the lock screen.

Comment: I want a pop-up message to appear on top of the lock screen on older versions not only lollilop

Answer (score 0):

You can use "service" for this case. For example: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

From a service you can create your own dialog without activity:
[How to display a Dialog from a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918571/how-to-display-a-dialog-from-a-service)

Comment: Can he see the dialog on top of the lock screen?