# How to show alert messages popup from background service when app is in background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog, background-service

I need to show an alert message to the user when anything changes on server. I am using a background service for fetching any new updates from server after every 60 sec. Currently I am using notifications to notify user about the update but what I want is, to show an alert message popup for the same whether the app is in background or foreground. Please suggest what should I do to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do that, because it's against the design/style guidelines from Android. The only way you should do that is via notification-system.

But look at this answer. Maybe that's also a way you could go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7918720/2653134