# System level alert dialog in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog, background-service

I want to show system level alert dialog in background service, I found [How to display a Dialog from a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19269931/1539100) but this answer use

```
dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

and I could not find it in Xamarin `AlertDialog` API.

What can I do now?

Did I miss any things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.SetTitle("Confirm delete");
    alert.SetMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.");
    alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) => {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Ok button Tapped!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    });

    Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
    dialog.Window.SetType(Android.Views.WindowManagerTypes.SystemAlert);
    dialog.Show();
```

Comment: What if from simple class needs to show system alert where you can not use context 'this'. How will you create system alert?