# Can I invoke an Alertdialog from a service in Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

An `AlertDialog` can be invoked from a `service` which is possible ([link for the same](http://tofu0913.blogspot.in/2013/07/popup-alertdialog-in-android-service.html)), but had a doubt here, like invoking an alert dialog from a android service is against Google UI guidelines or not ? If I do so will my developed application fail certification ?

Comment: `An AlertDialog can be invoked from a service` that's wrong, it can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It highly recomended to not do this, check the below post on stackoverflow [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918571/how-to-display-a-dialog-from-a-service)

And if even want to do that

```
dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

`TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` window layout parameter to Dialog

need additional permission for this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> An AlertDialog can be invoked from a service which is possible

Not really. The blog post that you link two shows two options:

1. Do not use `AlertDialog`, but instead use a dialog-themed activity
2. Use `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`, which is a complicated permission and one that users may not grant to you

Of the two, the first is a much better answer.

> like invoking an alert dialog from a android service is against Google UI guidelines or not ?

I do not know what you consider "Google UI guidelines" to be. I do not recall Material Design addressing this issue.

However, popping up a UI from the background is very user-hostile. You do not know what the user is doing in the foreground. For example, if the user is trying to use a navigation app, your dialog may cause a car crash.

Please use a notification — perhaps a heads-up notification — rather than displaying a dialog from the background.

> If I do so will my developed application fail certification ?

You would have to ask whoever is certifying your app. There is no standard certification process in Android.

For the Play Store, Google has their [app developer policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/), and you would need to see whether your dialog would violate any of those policies.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design  Check this link it states that Use the notification system — don't use dialog boxes in place of notifications
If your background service needs to notify a user, use the standard notification system — don't use a dialog or toast to notify them.

Comment: @MurtazaKapadia: First, that document is deprecated. Second, that document specifically tells you what I did (see "Use the notification system — don't use dialog boxes in place of notifications").