# To pop up a message during an incoming call/

Tags: android

I need my app to pop up a message on incoming call if the battery is critically low. Is there any way to do this(and if possible cut the call)? searching in the net didnot help me much.

Comment: First - catch the incoming call: http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html Second - read battery state: http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/getting-battery-information-on-android.html Third - end incoming call: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481524/how-to-programatically-answer-end-a-call-in-android-4-1  For all this you have to use `BradcastReceivers` and `Intents`. And, I guess, you will need to have a `service` in order to accomplish your task

Comment: what exactly couldn't you find on the net..?

Comment: Can I toast or pop dialogue box when phone rings?

Comment: dialogue from service - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599563/android-alert-dialog-from-service . `Toast` will work fine

Comment: My friend says nothing can be done when a call comes till it gets cut, because android gives first priority to calls and they can't be interrupted. I am really confused. Any clue?

Comment: I dunno, try implementing and see what happens

Comment: After a brief googling i found that it is possible, but not on all devices and not on all API levels. But i might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use this for showing something during incoming call

```
 public class IncomingCallReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context mContext;
private Intent mIntent;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;
    mIntent = intent;
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int events = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE;
    tm.listen(phoneStateListener, events);
}

private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        String callState = "UNKNOWN";
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            callState = "IDLE";



            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            //  write your code display Toast or Dialog







            break;

        }
        Log.i(">>>Broadcast", "onCallStateChanged " + callState);
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
};
```

}

Declare this way in your menifest file

```
 <receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReciever"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Add Following Permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```