# Android Error: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

Hy. I tried to create an alert dialog but when I run my application, is throw an exception

```
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:687)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at com.example.stampp.UI.Rewards.DeleteRewardsFragment$1.onItemClick(DeleteRewardsFragment.java:80)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1394)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3024)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3846)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5629)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1725)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1970)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1970)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1970)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1970)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1970)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1970)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1970)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2062)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1400)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2369)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2010)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5809)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3130)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2658)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:1015)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2667)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
09-26 12:43:21.949: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my code:

```
public class DeleteRewardsFragment extends Fragment{

private Context context;

private FragmentsActivity activity;

private ListView listView;
private View myFragmentView;
private DeleteRewardsAdapter adapter;
private String[] values;

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) myFragmentView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);


    activity = (FragmentsActivity) getActivity();
    context = activity.getApplicationContext();

    values = new String[4];

    adapter = new DeleteRewardsAdapter(context, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(deleteEvent);

    return myFragmentView;

}

private OnItemClickListener deleteEvent = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialog .setTitle("Jetzt löschen?");
        alertDialog .setMessage("Die in deisem Store gesammelten stampss gehen debei verloren!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        values = new String[values.length-1];
                        adapter = new DeleteRewardsAdapter(context, values);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Löschen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
        dialog.show();

    }
};

}
```

Can someone to help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dialog throwing "Unable to add window — token null is not for an application” with getApplication() as context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To add `AlertDialog` to your `Activity` or `Fragment` you have to use your `Activity`'s instance, not your application's which you are doing in your code. Create your `AlertDialog` like this :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

And that should do the trick for you! : )

Comment: how to do it in a service?

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31221469/6144372 You can say thanks later! :)

Answer (score 14):

In my case I was trying to create my dialog like this:

```
new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
```

So I had to change for:

```
new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
```

And it started working.

Answer (score 7):

Below are the things you can do to get it over from issue.

1. Instead of using

   ```
     context
   ```

   you should use

   ```
     ActivityName.this
   ```
2. if you are using getApplicationContext(), then use below flag before using getApplicationContext ()

   ```
     dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT)
   ```

Add the following permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I changed:

```
ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
```

to:

```
ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
```

,

Answer (score 3):

Send in activity, rather than context.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed `getApplicationContext()`
 to

```
activity.this
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

Change from `getApplicationContext()` or `getApplication()` to `ActivityName.this`

For more information, look at this [Dialog throwing "Unable to add window — token null is not for an application” with getApplication() as context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi)

Answer (score 0):

**Because of inappropriate Context:**

You need to be ensured that the Context you provide is the activity context.

> `AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder`(***provide activity Context here***);

Answer (score 0):

**Struggle on it long time!**

If you has this issue in Android SDK 26+, it is caused by bellow wrong setting:

mWindowParams.type = LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;

> TYPE_TOAST: 
>   This constant was deprecated in API level 26. for
>   non-system apps. Use TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY instead.

[SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW PERMISSION on API 26 not working as expected. Permission denied for window type 2002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867533/system-alert-window-permission-on-api-26-not-working-as-expected-permission-den)

Answer (score 0):

Add the permission on manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```