# Make System alert window run nicely

Tags: java, android, service, system-alert-window

I am new to android dev and little knowledge of java.I want to know how to inflate a layout from service using `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`

```
public void checkDrawOverlayPermission() {
 /* check if we already  have 
  permission to draw over 
  other apps */
  
 if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23) {
    if  (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) 
 {
    /* if not construct intent to request permission */
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    /* request permission via start activity for result */
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    else {
        createOnTopView();
 }}}}
```

I used that to get permission↑↑↑

```
@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  Intent data) {
/* check if received result code
 is equal our requested code for draw permission  */
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
 /* if so check once again if we have permission */
    if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        createOnTopView();
    }
}
 }
```

after I run this on my phone Teckno k7 ,android 6.0
It runs well buh can't run on my friend's phone Techno F2.it crashes on his phone.
Please help me.

Comment: What Android version is your friends phone?

Comment: @HapaxLegomenon android 9.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45867612/16430579 this may answer your question, I don't know what createOnTopView() does exactly so I can't be sure.

Comment: @HapaxLegomenon its a method to start the service to inflate the layout