# Android Starting Dialog from Service

Tags: android, service, dialog

I am trying to open a dialog from a Service in Android:

```
MeasurementsStarter.measurementsstarter.createConsciousnessDialog();
```

createConsciousnessDialog:

```
public void createConsciousnessDialog() {
    consciousnessDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Bent u bij bewustzijn?")
            .setMessage(
                    "U heeft al 30 seconden niet bewogen, bent u nog bij bewustzijn")
            .setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    MeasuringService.measuringservice.resetSensorBooleans();
                }
            }).show();
}
```

but when I it should open. it gets called, but nothing happens except for this(LogCat):

```
Failure getting entry for 0x010802c9 (t=7 e=713) in package 0 (error -75)
Attempting to initialize hardware acceleration outside of the main thread, aborting
```

I hope someone can help me out, thanks

Comment: can you post the snippet from `resetSensorBooleans()` method

Comment: The resetSensorBooleans() method only resets some flags for me, nohting else.

Comment: This works for me. Try is out! http://stackoverflow.com/a/19269931/3451686

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alert dialog from Android service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599563/alert-dialog-from-android-service)