# What context to pass from an IntentHandler to a method that needs one?

Tags: android, android-context, android-intentservice

I just added a check for a new condition that can arise in a long-working app that uses "borrowed" code to display a message.

The statement is inside the `IntentHandler` for class `DbQuery`, which `extends IntentService`:

```
showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "title", "note", mDatabase); // LINE 576 ****
```

`showMessage` is defined in class `Utilities` and had always worked, until I decided to see that it works on my Android 4 tablet (19):

```
  public static void showMessage(Context mContext, String tit, String mm, SQLiteDatabase m)
  {
    TextView message = new TextView(mContext);
    TextView title   = new TextView(mContext);
    title.setText(tit);
    message.setText(mm);
    showCenteredInfoDialog(mContext, title, message, Gravity.CENTER, m); // **** LINE 505
  }
```

It calls the method where the exception occurs (marked with *****):

```
  public static void showCenteredInfoDialog
      (
              Context context, TextView message, TextView title, int 
              gravity, SQLiteDatabase m
      )
  {
    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUTINFLATERSERVICE);

    int YELLOWFOREGROUND ;
    int BRIGHTBLUEBACKGROUND ;

    {
      YELLOWFOREGROUND = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.yellowforeground, null);
      BRIGHTBLUEBACKGROUND =
          context.getResources().getColor(R.color.brightbluebackground, null);

      title.setTextColor(YELLOWFOREGROUND);
      title.setBackgroundColor(BRIGHTBLUEBACKGROUND);
      title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

      AlertDialog.Builder
          builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
          builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
          builder.setCustomTitle(title);
          builder.setMessage(message.getText());

      AlertDialog
          dialog;
          dialog = builder.show(); // *************************** LINE 482
          dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

      TextView
      messageView = /*(TextView)*/ dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
      messageView.setTextColor(YELLOWFOREGROUND);
      messageView.setBackgroundColor(BRIGHTBLUEBACKGROUND);
      messageView.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
      messageView.setGravity(gravity);
    }
  }
```

Calls to `showMessage` work from `MainActivity`, where the `Context` passed is `this`.

**I suppose I just shouldn't try to call `showMessage` from my `IntentHandler`, BUT I'd like to know how I SHOULD call it. 
I.e., what `Context` should I pass?**

For the first argument to `showMessage`, I've tried `this`, `getApplicationContext()`, `getApplication()`, `getApplication().getApplicationContext()`, and `getBaseContext()`. All return the following error. I even supplied a listener instead of `null` as the 2nd argument to builder.setPositiveButton. Same error:

```
E: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[QueryDb]
    Process: com.dslomer64.sqhell, PID: 24814
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
                                     token null is not for an application
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:571)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
        at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1112)
        at com.dslomer64.sqhell.Utilities.showCenteredInfoDialog(Utilities.java:482)
        at com.dslomer64.sqhell.Utilities.showMessage(Utilities.java:505)
        at com.dslomer64.sqhell.QueryDb.onHandleIntent(QueryDb.java:576)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
E: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb40fe560
```

There follows a printscreen of part of a debug trace.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599563/alert-dialog-from-android-service you can try this

Comment: Your IntentService may be working when there're no Activities around.

Comment: @nishant--Thanks. The link refers us to `android-smspopup`, which supposely does exactly that. It looks like a lot more effort than I have energy/patience for right now, but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @user8035311--good point. I'm self-taught at Java and Android and that pretty much means I assumed my prior programming expertise entitled me to just jump in, apply what I know, and ask about what I don't know, the result being gaping holes in my knowledge base and understanding. But your comment did indeed fill one of those holes. Thanks. The more I think about it, the clearer `Context` becomes. *Clearer*, still not totally clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, Android `Service` may be running when there're no activities around. It's just another core entity in Android like `Activity` or `BroadcastReceiver`.

It's cleaner, if your Android `Service` doesn't take the responsibility for updating the UI but rather sends enough data to your `Activity` that can use to update the UI. For instance, your `Android Service` could use `Broadcast` to send messages around and the `Activity` could listen to those messages via `BroadcastReceiver`.

Define `BROADCAST_FILTER` in your `Service` so that `BroadcastReceiver` could identify that a message intent comes from the service:

```
public static String BROADCAST_FILTER = <Your service class>.class.getName();
```

Send an intent form your `Service`:

```
//send a broadcast intent from your service
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(BROADCAST_FILTER);
intent.putExtra("message", "<your message here>")
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Register `BroadcastReceiver` inside your `Activity`:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra();
        Utils.showMessage(<your activity>.this, ...);
        //do your update here
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    //make sure your onReceive receives only the messages with this action
    filter.addAction(<Your Service>.BROADCAST_FILTER);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

Comment: @user805311--The fact is that I'd already tried doing more or less what you've suggested before I read your reply. However my approach definitely isn't as sound as yours appears to be. I couldn't apply it because `BROADCAST_FILTER` isn't to be found in the `Intent` world. I'm going to provide my own "Answer", explaining how I (had) applied your suggestion but give you credit for the Answer, as I'm about to do. Thank you.

Comment: @DSlomer64 Thanks for your comment and sorry for omitting the definition of BROADCAST_FILTER. I edited my answer - hopefully it is a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the activity context for this error and i hope resolved this error.

private Context context

initialise this context in onCreate method like this

context = this; // and use this context

> showMessage(context, "title", "note", mDatabase);

And also create a context type variable in singleton class use as a global verialbe

Comment: @Vijendra--I tried using `public Context gContext` in `MainActivity`, which might be okay if I'd planned for the app to be a singleton. Anyway, I wound up with the same error  message. I thought I got errors with `showMessage(context...` with `context = this`, but it's been a few days and now I can't replicate it. I'll try to do so and get back to you. However, where I want to show the message is in an `IntentService`, not an `Activity`, so there's no `onCreate` to initialize in.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the nature of my app, I already had a `BroadcastManager` and a `BroadcastReceiver` in place before asking my question, so I had already tried a weak attempt of my own, similar to what @user805311 suggested.

And I was essentially right in saying I just shouldn't try to `showMessage` in an `IntentService`, though @nishant's link shows how it can be done.

The changes I made to existing code were as follows:

In `publishProgress` in the `IntentService` for `QueryDb`, I added code to the `if` at the top to deliver the message (stored in `progress`) via another `Intent` instead of `showMessage`, which caused exceptions, and immediately began shutting down the process via `onPostExecute`:

```
public class QueryDb extends IntentService
{
  ...
  private void publishProgress(String progress) 
  {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MatchesActivity.SOME_ACTION);

    if(progress.toLowerCase().startsWith("Revise"))
    {
      intent.putExtra(MatchesActivity.STRING_EXTRA_NAME, progress);
      onPostExecute();
    }
    else ...
    ...
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

It's called like so at the point during execution where going further would be fruitless:

```
  String messageText = "Revise code!";
  publishProgress(messageText);
```

The published message text is interpreted like so, inside `MatchesActivity`, which had initiated the `IntentService` and begun to listen for messages.

This is the first place `showMessage` finally worked.

```
public class MatchesActivity extends Activity implements QueryDb.DbProcListenerForQueryDb
{
  private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver  = new BroadcastReceiver()
  {
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
      String s = intent.getStringExtra(STRING_EXTRA_NAME) ;
      if(s.startsWith("Revise"))
      {
         showMessage(_context, "Oh, no...", s, null);
         MatchesActivity.this.setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
      }
      else ...
      ...
    };  // BroadcastReceiver
```

But to continue with my quest to `showMessage` with acceptable `Context`, I removed the `showMessage` from the code just above and put one in `onActivityResult` in `MainActivity`, where it also worked in `onActivityResult` where the "bad news" about canceling was received and processed:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{ 
  ...
  @Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentData)
  {
    if(resultCode != RESULT_OK)
    {
      showMessage(this, "Bad news", "Only Scrabble", mDatabase);
      return;
    }
    ...
```

Long story short, moving `showMessage` from `QueryDb`--which doesn't extend Activity--into `MatchesActivity` or `MainActivity` eliminated error about `Context`.