# EditText not displaying keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keyboard

I have an `EditText` in a service but when I click on it my keyboard doesn't show up. 
Any reasons for this? or is there some extra code for showing keyboard? but the `EditText` still acts like one. For example, I tried to copy random text and tried to past it and it works just fine but just that the keyboard isn't showing when I click on it. Please help me out

Code

```
private EditText messageArea;
```

onCreate

```
 messageArea = (EditText) myview.findViewById(R.id.input_message);
```

XML

```
        <EditText
        android:paddingVertical="5dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:hint="Write a message..."
        android:id="@+id/input_message"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/add_image"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/send_message" />
```

Its a service and not an activity or a fragment

Code

```
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            750, 1250,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;

    wm.addView(myview, params);
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Kindly post your code snippet of activity and layout XML

Comment: Look to the edited question @Vall0n

Comment: Done... Also its a service @Kishita

Comment: Check in another device.

Comment: Same result @Khemraj...

Comment: Check if keyboard is not disabled anywhere in your code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636686/6891563

Comment: But i have no such code... So how can i enable it if its disabled? because i have never seen any example of an edittext in service so im not sure @Khemraj

Comment: Or is there some code for opening keyboard in android? @Khemraj Like programatically

Comment: It is default behaviour that If you click on EditText then your keyboard opens.

Comment: What should i do now? @Khemraj

Comment: Maybe create my own keyboard or something? @Khemraj

Comment: Make a new sample app, run in your mobile, there is something in your device or your code that is blocking keyboard, you must identify that. By making sample app you will be clear if that is your code issue or device issue.

Comment: @MichelleKinsten Why did you do the ui in a service? Why not use an activity or fragment?

Comment: @MichelleKinsten Yes this is the issue, can you try an activity/dialog/fragment-dialog?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3599563/6891563

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3606596/6891563

Comment: I want it over other apps... Can i programatically get an editText in Service? @Vall0n

Comment: Yeah new activities open from my service... just the edittext isnt opening... @Khemraj

Comment: There is no fault in code... i created a basic service and tried to put edittext in there and try it and it still isnt opening keyboard @Khemraj

Comment: Can you show code of opening EditText from your service?

Comment: I got the error... Thanks for ur effort man @Khemraj

Comment: As I said EditText default behaviour is showing keyboard, your code was blocking keyboard.

Comment: That's why we say, whenever you ask question then show code always. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
    android:paddingVertical="5dp"
    android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
    android:hint="Write a message..."
    android:id="@+id/input_message"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/add_image"
```

change it to this. You have given textcolor **white** that's why it is not showing up.Change it to black or any other color to show up there.

Comment: But the background is black

Comment: try making the height to wrap_content. @MichelleKinsten

Comment: you are saying background is black but there is no background attribute in edittext. which background is black?

Comment: android:background="@null"

Comment: but how does color relate to keyboard not opening

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in here

```
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            750, 1250,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

I had to remove FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE as that was preventing the keyboard from opening...

I replaced it with

```
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            750, 1250,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```