# PopUp while receiving Incoming Call

Tags: android

I want to create a popup alert based on some criteria of incoming number. Anyhow I created a toast message based on the criteria. However I stuck at the point of creating alert. Please help.

```
//IncomingNumberCheck.java


public class IncomingNumberCheck extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            Toast.makeText(context, networkProvider(incomingNumber), LENGTH_LONG).show();


        } else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE) || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Call ended", LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public String networkProvider(String incomingNumber) {
        if(incomingNumber.startsWith("some string") || incomingNumber.startsWith("some string")) {
            return "Particular provider name";
        } else {
            return "Other user";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to open an activity which has transparent background , generally we used this method for make pop up when incoming call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialog is built by ui context. The approach to show dialog without ui context (activity) in some case: call dialog in rest api, show dialog after own activity finish, call dialog in first activity and want to show it in the next activity also.

**First: use Broadcast receiver**

Assume: We call open dialog after delay timeout and run TestActivity concurrently in MainActivity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Alerts {
    public static void register(Activity activity) {
        AlertReceiver.register(activity);
    }

    public static void unregister(Activity activity) {
        AlertReceiver.unregister(activity);
    }

    public static void displayError(Context context, String msg) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("MyApplication.INTENT_DISPLAYERROR");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
    }

    private static void displayErrorInternal(Context context, String msg) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Error").setMessage(msg).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    private static class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static HashMap<Activity, AlertReceiver> registrations;

        static {
            registrations = new HashMap<Activity, AlertReceiver>();
        }

        private Context activityContext;

        private AlertReceiver(Activity activity) {
            activityContext = activity;
        }

        static void register(Activity activity) {
            AlertReceiver receiver = new AlertReceiver(activity);
            activity.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("MyApplication.INTENT_DISPLAYERROR"));
            registrations.put(activity, receiver);
        }

        static void unregister(Activity activity) {
            AlertReceiver receiver = registrations.get(activity);
            if (receiver != null) {
                activity.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                registrations.remove(activity);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            abortBroadcast();
            String msg = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            displayErrorInternal(activityContext, msg);
        }
    }

}
```

In MainActivity

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Alerts.displayError(getApplicationContext(), "test Error");
    }
}, 500);
startActivity(new Intent(this, TestActivity.class));
finish();
```

In TestActivity or any activity want to show this dialog

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Alerts.register(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Alerts.unregister(this);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Make sure declare 2 activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity_">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TestActivity"/>
</application>
```

**Another way: Use permission**

Just add this before your `alertDialog.show();`

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

and use this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

And now, you can use applicationContext() for dialog builder

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        builder.setTitle("Error").setMessage("test").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        alert.show();
    }
}, 500);
startActivity(new Intent(this, TestActivity.class));
finish();
```

**Another way:** use single context in application and update in each activity (but careful with leak memory, improve it as your way)

You can have a static Context in your Application like this:

```
public static Context CurrentContext;
```

and a custom abstract Activity that sets currentContext upon creation like this:

```
public abstract class CustomActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyApplication.CurrentContext = this;
    }
}
```

Then you would get context like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dlgBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyApplication.CurrentContext);
 dlgBuilder.setTitle("Context Example");
 dlgBuilder.setMessage("I am being shown from the application Static context!");
 dlgBuilder.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
dlgBuilder.show();
```

Comment: displayAlert() should be static to access from my broadcast class. So I can't pass context as parameter

Comment: I created a static context and pass it as a parameter. But the app closes when call is receiving

Comment: @dilanMD check my answer again. Updated.

Comment: @dilanMD If my answer solved your issue, accept my answer.

Comment: I'm trying it now

Comment: It's working fine. I've tried it with an AlertDialog. Now I'll change that to desired UI from that activity. Thanks a lot. You're a genius.

Comment: @dilanMD Good job. please accept my answer and give up vote to my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild idea here... 
Try using a service to listen for incoming calls then create a dialog from the service. 
Have a look at this...  [Alert dialog from Android service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599563/alert-dialog-from-android-service)

Answer (score 0):

**Use this custom dialog with layout and without required transparent Activity**

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;

​
public class SendyDailog {

    public static Dialog show(final Context context) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(1);
        dialog.getWindow().addFlags(2);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0.7f);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.item_progress);
        dialog.show();
        return dialog;
    }

}
```

> 1. set Your Custom Layout to R.layout.item_progress
> 2. Its Completely Works in my app So Try It